# Azure Functions: Can I have different configuration for BlobTriggered function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a .Net project which contains, multiple trigger in a same azure function project (a blob triggered function & a Queue triggered function).

I need a different concurrency for my blob triggered function from queue triggered function.

I know that the blob trigger uses a queue internally.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---poison-blobs

Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Use a different function app for that case.

Comment: what do you mean by different concurrency ?

Comment: @Thomas Concurrency settings like bactchSize and newBatchThreshold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Sebastian has said, I am afraid you can only achieve this by putting blobtrigger in another Function app.

Settings in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings) regulate behavior of the whole Function app. And We can't separately customize settings for each trigger.

In your case, queue message concurrency settings(bactchSize and newBatchThreshold) influence all triggers that consume messages concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using blob trigger, you should try eventgrid trigger:

- [Reacting to Blob storage events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview)
- [Event Grid trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid)

Using the eventgrid trigger which is a "custom" http trigger, any time a blob is added/deleted in any containers of your storage account, your endpoint will be called without any delay.